# Detect Gesture Velocity in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am looking for a way to detect the gesture velocity in Flutter. Like assume that you want to detect vertical gesture. Is it possible to detect how fast user swiped and apply action accordingly?

I have googled but could not find a way to detect velocity of gesture in Flutter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DragEndDetails` passed to the `onXXXDragEnd` callback of `GestureDetector` contains the velocity.

Comment: Richard Heap, thank you very much for your answer. Your answer gave me a point to detect the velocity of gesture. So only I need to use it to do some action based on Velocity. I Mark it as accepted answer.